# Microsoft Edge - Poor Performance after Anniversary Update

Tags: windows-10, performance, microsoft-edge

I have a surface pro 4 with an I7 2.2 G processor and 16 GB memory, since installing the Win10 Anniversary Update, Microsoft Edge has become an absolute dog, to the point it crumbles my entire machine.

Running other (and multiple) applications work just fine, I can run photoshop, visual studio, office apps, chrome\firefox - all concurrently - and the machine runs like a champ.  However, if I run Edge (sometimes ONLY Edge) - within minutes I hear the fans start to kick up in the machine, websites start to react slowly (both my interaction with them and the loading of the content), the mouse cursor starts to get choppy, and eventually I need to use task manager to kill the process. It almost feels like theres a memory leak or a loop that starts running in the background.

I've avoided using Edge since the Anny Update thinking future windows updates would perhaps resolve the issue, but just this morning I gave Edge another go, and sure enough after a few minutes the browser is just not nearly as responsive as it used to be.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?  Any thoughts to a fix?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: does the edge process has a high CPU usage?

Comment: thx for the reply @magicandre, sorry for the delay.  Correct, high cpu results in using edge, even if i load a page and leave it in the background.  Just now my fans were even running for hours on end, edge was taking 50-70% cpu, once i closed edge the fans stopped within 30 seconds...

Comment: ok, open a cmd.exe as admin and run this command and capture the CPU usage of Edge: **wpr.exe -start EdgeBrowser && timeout -1 && wpr.exe -stop C:\HighCPUUsage.etl**. Zip the large ETL file (+ NGENPDB fodler) into 1 zip, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: have you captured the trace of the CPU usage?

Comment: Thanks @magicandre, try here: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AifYBi0TiUD-gYDwY_qkSbZMZQcom1g - I was able to gen the etl file, but wasnt able to find an NGENPDB directory anywhere, if there's a spot I should look for that please let me know, thx again!

Comment: the trace is very short. replace -1 with 120 to get 2 minutes. Some CPu usage is caused by Flash (ads on website).

Comment: Thanks again @magicandre1981.  I just added another zip to my shared directory and ran for 2 minutes. I also disabled flash in edge before running these traces, but performance was still poor for me.. but thought I'd mention. thx!

Comment: now, most CPU usage is caused by the Chakra Engine which tries to do memory cleanup (Chakra.dll!Memory::Recycler::DoBackgroundWork)

Comment: Thanks @magicandre1981, so what does that mean?  Is it a MS bug that we just have to wait on?  Are there settings I can tweak?

Comment: I have no idea how to solve it. Also some CPU usgae is done by the HTML engine to draw the Canvas. Submit the issue in the feedback hub to Microsoft and attach the ETL file, so that the Edge devs can look at it.